# why calling repaint in this code?

Tags: java, swing, applet, repaint, jcomponent

if you add a jpanel instance to the content pane, the paintComponent method is called, right?

> content_pane.add (fDrawingPanel);

so why would you call "repaint" at the first line in the `run()` method? (it says "to paint the loading message, but it should already be painted, because `paintComponent` was called before, and once `fShow` is true, we don't set it back to false, so this code is, i think, supposed to be called once ) :

```
public class MediaTrackApplet extends JApplet
                       implements Runnable
{
  // Need a reference to the panel for the
  // thread loop.
  DrawingPanel fDrawingPanel;

  // Parameters to track the image
  MediaTracker fTracker;
  Image fImg;
  int fImageNum = 0;
  boolean fShow = false;
  String fMessage ="Loading...";

  /** Use a MediaTracker to load an image.**/
  public void init () {
    Container content_pane = getContentPane ();

    // Create an instance of DrawingPanel
    fDrawingPanel = new DrawingPanel (this);

    // Add the DrawingPanel to the contentPane.
    content_pane.add (fDrawingPanel);

    // Get image and monitor its loading.
    fImg = getImage (getCodeBase (), "m20.gif.jpg" );
    fTracker = new MediaTracker (this);

    // Pass the image reference and an ID number.
    fTracker.addImage (fImg, fImageNum);
  } // init

  /** If the image not yet loaded, run the thread
    * so the run() will monitor the image loading.
   **/
  public void start () {
    if (!fTracker.checkID (fImageNum) ) {
        Thread thread = new Thread (this);
        thread.start ();
    } else
        // Unloading/reloading web page can will leave
        // checkID true but fShow will be false.
        fShow = true;
  } // start

  /** Use a thread to wait for the image to load 
    * before painting it.
   **/
  public void run ()  {
    // Paint the loading message
    repaint ();
    // The wait for the image to finish loading
    try {
      fTracker.waitForID (fImageNum );
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    // Check if there was a loading error
    if (fTracker.isErrorID (fImageNum ))
        fMessage= "Error";
    else
        fShow = true;
    // Repaint with the image now if it loaded OK
    repaint ();
  } // run

}// class MediaTrackApplet


/** This JPanel subclass draws an image on the panel if
  * the image is loaded. Otherwise, it draws a text message.
 **/
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
  MediaTrackApplet parent = null;

  DrawingPanel (MediaTrackApplet parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }// ctor

  public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent (g);

    // Add your drawing instructions here
    if (parent.fShow)
        g.drawImage (parent.fImg,10,10,this);
    else
        g.drawString (parent.fMessage, 10,10);
  } // paintComponent

} // class DrawingPanel
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not try to comment the repaint line and try to run it and see the results instead of asking a question here?

Comment: Or, if you're using an IDE you can set a breakpoint in the painting code and run it in debug mode

Comment: Most of that code has become redundant since the introduction of the `ImageIO` class.  It blocks while loading images, so the `MediaTracker` is not needed.

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: thanks guys for your answers, @Andrew Thompson Andrew can you tell me more about this? @trashgod are you referring to the `EDT` ? paintComponent already paints the component, so i dont know why we call `repaint` do you have any idea? @MadcoreTom thanks, i've never done that, can you tell more about it? and will it tell me "why" we call repaint there?

Comment: *"can you tell me more about this?"* Sure, but I'm not about to write a treatise on the subject.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson i did not understand "what" blocks the loading of the images? the mediaTracker? also what method would you use instead of addImage? is `ImageIcon`a better way to do it?

Comment: The method [`Applet.getImage(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29) is asynchronous (**not** blocking) so a `MediaTracker` is required to check on the loading of the image.  The `ImageIO.read(File/URL/InputStream)` **does** block.  By the time the method finishes, it either returns a valid, complete image or throws an `Exception`.  Hence an image loaded by `ImageIO` needs no tracker. `ImageIcon` has it's own media tracker I believe, but don't create one if you don't need an `ImageIcon` - just use `ImageIO` instead.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : okay, so i should (always?) use `ImageIO.read()` in a separate thread? and do you know about the redondant `repaint` method in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you referring to the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?

Yes. This venerable, but superannuated, example hails from an era that predates our modern understanding that Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). The initial invocation of `repaint()` has the effect of posting a new `Runnable` on the `EventQueue`, while allowing the background thread to finish loading images in anticipation of the subsequent `repaint()`. See also [*Memory Consistency Properties*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) and this related [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway).

Comment: But `paintComponent` already paints the graphics in the `EDT`, doesn't it? in the code, we add the loading text by default when we add the panel into the content pane, then : the first repaint is called to load (again) the loading message (this is what i don't understand : this double call to paintComponent before loading the images), and only then: we're loading the images with `waitForID` .

Comment: The example is incorrectly synchronized, and it should be deprecated. It looks like it was _supposed_ to show the "Loading" message while the image loaded and subsequently paint the image or an error message.

Comment: mmh okay, so i thought i did not understand the meaning of the first repaint, but it looks like it's not mandatory : i can only use the second repaint in the `run()` method right?

Comment: No; at a minimum, there's a data race on `fShow`. The run time behavior of this program may vary from one machine to another. @Andrew Thompson's comments suggest a more reliable approach. If you need to load images in the background, use `SwingWorker`.